# CC2533 chip is not recognized by CC debugger

Tags: debugging, texas-instruments

I'm trying to connect CC debugger to a board with CC2533
I've connected GND,DC,DD,RST between the boards.
The board is powered externally with 5V.
I've powered the target board and connected the debugger to my computer using USB.
The debugger LED is red.

Is "Target Voltage Sense" pin required?
if yes, can I connect it to 5V?
If no, should it be connected to any AVDDx/DVDDx ?

Did I miss anything else?
Thanks.

Comment: In the "absolute maximum ratings" table of your datasheet, note that it is forbidden to apply voltage to any digital pin (which includes the debug pins) when the chip is not powered.  The "target voltage sense" pin should therefore be tied to the same rail that powers your CC2533, so the debugger will not send signals to an unpowered chip.